# Do this in C# code instead of template XAML

Tags: silverlight, templates, datagrid, resources

Is there a way to make column of cells in a Silverlight datagrid be readonly in editmode with C# code instead of setting up a entire datagrid as a template in a resource file?

**UPDATE**
Found an example piece of code - 
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/17483/58189.aspx

In the response by slhungry midway into the thread. He has example code written as a XAML template. Can you write this in C#?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can certainly create [`DataGridColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn(VS.95).aspx) programmatically in your codebehind and add them to your `DataGrid`:

```
DataGridColumn myColumn = new DataGridColumn();
```

Then you can easily configure the properties:

```
myColumn.Header = "tyndall's New Column";

myColumn.IsReadOnly = true; // All cells in column will be readonly
```

You can also programmatically set up binding in the codebehind, if you wish. Finally, you can add this column to the datagrid:

```
myDataGrid.Columns.Add(myColumn);
```

Does this help answer your question?

Comment: What if you wanted to make the text selectable but take away the edit mode basically. Don't you just have to put it in ReadOnly while in Edit Mode. I'm having trouble finding the snippet I saw online with the XAML template code. I'll continue to look for it