# How do you dynamically assign a datagrid's headers in c#?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

How do you dynamically assign a datagrid's headers in c#?

Consider the following XAML:

```
        <data:DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="1,1,1,1" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Substantive"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Substantive}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />

                <data:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header=""
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Month[0]}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />

                <data:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header=""
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Month[1]}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />

            </data:DataGrid.Columns>

        </data:DataGrid>
```

In the C# code, how would I define the headers that are blank?

OK, well, if no one knows, let's go with a different question.  How does one create a DataGrid from scratch in C# code instead of in XAML?

Comment: xarzu: Might I suggest some patience before you radically change your question, not everyone who could be of help to you is active on SO at the same time.  SO is globally used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add columns to a datagrid as such(for textcolumn):

```
text2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
bind = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("ValueList");
bind.ConverterParameter = i;
bind.Converter = new IndexConverter();             
text2.Binding = bind;
text2.Header = "Header";
text2.MaxWidth = 100;
....           
datagrid1.Columns.Add(text2);
```

You can allso access an existing column via:

```
((DataGridTextColumn)datagrid1.Columns[i]).Header = "Header";
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you need but:

- Creating new columns including header etc. see [Do this in C# code instead of template XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3635947/do-this-in-c-code-instead-of-template-xaml)
- change the header of a column see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.header%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your orignal question it would seem to me that a value converter would do the job here.

```
public class MyConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         // Do stuff with parameter, for example:-

         int month = Convert.ChangeType(parameter, typeof(int), culture);
         return cultrue.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(month + 1);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then use it in your xaml:-

```
     <UserControl.Resources>
          <local:MyConverter x:Key="myconv" />
     </UserControl.Resources>
     ...
        <data:DataGrid  x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  Margin="1,1,1,1" >
            <data:DataGrid.Columns>
                <data:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="Substantive"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Substantive}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />

                <data:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myconv} ConverterParameter=0}"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Month[0]}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />

                <data:DataGridTextColumn
                    Header="{Binding Converter={StaticResource myconv} ConverterParameter=1}"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=Month[1]}"
                    IsReadOnly="True"
                    />

            </data:DataGrid.Columns>

        </data:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use    dataGrid.ItemsSource    your DataGrid headers will be asigned to the names of variables in List you use as ItemsSource.